# Method executed inside a Spring Rest Controller is significantly slower than in a pure java project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

**Background:**
I am working on a spring web application that provides an optimization algorithm to the users. The performance of my algorithm is acceptable when executed in a pure java project. However, calling it via a rest controller in a spring project leads to a massive performance gap which I would like to understand.

**Test/Observation:**
Of course, all tests are executed on the same hardware. The optimization algorithm is independent of spring, i.e. it receives some basic java objects as input and returns a result. As you can see in the table below, executing my algorithm takes at least twice as long inside spring which holds for 5 iterations and for 100 iterations (i.e. no constant overhead in the beginning).

| Iterations [No.] | Pure Java [ms] | Spring [ms] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | ~200 | ~ 400 |
| 100 | ~1400 | 3500 - 5000 |

I totally understand that a web application leads to some overhead on my machine (spring, angular, etc.). However, would you really expect such a massive performance impact? Essentially, this is only a small test data set and real world data sets will be more challenging.

To explain how I measured this in more detail:

- I have an `Optimization.class` which contains a `public static Result optimize(Data data){}`. `Data.class` is a POJO without any reference to spring entities.
- `optimize()` is an evolutionary algorithm with 5 or 100 iterations. The time given above is only measured inside `optimize()` but around the loop of iterations using `System.currentTimeInMillis()`. Hence, my method is only triggered once but executed for different number of iterations and I am only measuring how long these iterations in my algorithm take.
- `Pure Java` means that I created a `public static void main(String[] args)` that prepares `Data.class` and calls `optimize()`.
- `Spring` means that I created a rest controller that prepares `Data.class` and calls `optimize()`.

**Main Questions:**
I would highly appreciate any help to understand this issue in more detail. Currently I am thinking about the following questions:

- Which factors influence the performance of a method executed inside a spring rest controller?
- Can I somehow configure how the given hardware is used by spring?
- Is there any alternative to access an algorithm from the client, i.e. some alternative to the rest controller?
- Would it help to execute my algorithm in some asynchronous way and call the server again later to receive the result?

Comment: Where exactly have you measured those times? How exactly did you call your algorithm in both examples? And what possible differences do you have in the code? Without any examples, it's not possible to answer properly (any answers right now would be highly speculative about the reasons).

Comment: If you executed the 'pure Java code' scenario by calling your algorithm in a loop, it's quite likely that the way you structured your code made jvm optimize your method call away. To understand what I mean, see [this article](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/architect-benchmarking.html)

Comment: @dunni, crizzis, Eugene: I just updated my description to explain how I measure this. So I am not calling my algorithm in a loop, the algorithm is only triggered once and executed for a number of iterations.

Comment: the answer that I have provided still stands, even after your update.

Comment: @Eugene, if I understand you correctly, Spring creates proxies for the rest controllers. So there is of course some overhead when a `@RestController` is called. However, by the time `optimize()` is triggered, there should no longer be any proxies involved, right? This should simply be my created java code, right? So where does the performance gap come from?

Comment: @chrisb89 it will be close to impossible to answer this question without running a profiler, I think. As said in the answer, your are measuring _cold_ start of a method, these kind of measurements are unpredictable and are influenced by a lot of factors.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Using a population based optimization that runs millions of iterations is about 3times slower when triggered through spring rest controller than when triggered by pure java. I wouldn't consider an algorithm with millions of iterations that runs for minutes to be "cold start". The CPU load is pretty much the same, so are other settings like GC and memory.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the exact way you measured, these numbers could mean exactly zero (as in it is irrelevant what they are).

If you simply measured `5` and `100` executions, you have only measured "cold start" of those methods, and the fact that Spring is significantly slower is very expected; if you have an idea how Spring works under the hood. Spring will create proxies for all of your rest controller methods, that will go under a `tomcat` under the hood too... To simplify what I mean, throw an `Exception` in your `@RestController` and look at the stacktrace - you would be surprised of it's depth, I think.

The good news is that once you have *many* invocations of those rest methods, the `JVM` will optimize a lot of the things and calls will get a lot faster than the ones you made initially. Still, you will never be able to beat a plain method invocation vs calling it via a spring controller.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IntelliJ, you need to disable launch optimization (it's spring-specific option in run config). By default, IntelliJ adds the flag `-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1` for spring apps, which essentially prevents c2 compilation, hence making computation-heavy tasks significantly slower.

Source: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-297872